# How can I efficiently delete a repeated character from a string that has already been found in another string?

Tags: c++, string, char

Take this string as an example ("Hello World"). If you search for every vowel in this string and output it you'll get eoo. In this case I want 'o' not to be found again so it leaves you with only e and o.

This is the code that outputs "eoo" from "Hello World".

```
char a[256], v[6]="aeiou";
cin.get(a, 256);
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
    if(strchr(v, a[i])){
        cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

I've thought about erasing every vowel that I find from v,

> So if you find a[i] is a vowel, delete that vowel from v (e.g if a[i] is e, v becomes aiou.

I wonder if this is the most effective way to do so.

Comment: First and foremost, you don't have a `string`, but a fixed lengrh `char[]` array, and you cannot _delete_ any characters from it. What you can do is to shift in any characters from the right, and add another `NUL` at the new length.

Comment: Out of sheer, morbid curiosity, what would be your expected behavior if a character appeared multiple times in *both* strings. I.e. `"Hello, World" is your source string, and "aeioou" is your filter set?

Comment: Extending on the above, the best you can do with an array is to shift everything to the right of the character you want gone one space to the left to write over the "deleted" character. Don't forget to preserve the terminating null.

Comment: If you are concerned about "most effective", you might ask yourself how many times you want to call `strlen(a)`

Answer (score 2):

> I've thought about erasing every vowel that I find from v,

It likely is.

Note that if the number of searched elements is large, then using something such as `std::unordered_set` or similar would be more efficient. For a small set such as vowels, linear search is likely optimal.